# CSS: Can I put text over an image without having the text overflow?

Tags: css

I was wondering if it's possible to put text over an image without having it overflow. For example, if the text is too long, then it should just get cut off or use `ellipsis`.

This is what I have so far

```
.img{
    position: relative;
}

.text{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

However, with this code, a long text will overflow and run off the image. Is it possible to make it respect the parent's dimensions even though I'm using `absolute`?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the image a fixed size? Could just set the text class to the same width

Comment: @abney317 Unfortunately I'm trying to do this across all my images but all of my images have varying sizes

Answer (score 2):

You could try put everything inside a div

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <img />
    <p class="text">SOME LONG TEXT</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.text{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.img{
    width: 100%
}
.container{
    position: relative;
}
```